# firebase cloud function showing error while i use the 'context' in callable function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the cloud function where I try to call context To use the auth Token but it showing Error.

```
exports.checkCollege = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{ 

                  if(context.auth.token.moderator !== true){
                     return{
                        error:"Request not authorized. User must be a moderator to fulfill the request."
                     };
                  }
               const email = data.email;
              return grantModeratorRole(email).then(()=>{
                 return {
                    result: `Request fulfilled! ${email} email is now a moderator!`
                 }
              })
            })
```

It's showing this type of error:

```
src/index.ts:65:10 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

65       if(context.auth.token.moderator !== true){
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript definition for the context object is this:

```
/**
 * The interface for metadata for the API as passed to the handler.
 */
export interface CallableContext {
    /**
     * The result of decoding and verifying a Firebase Auth ID token.
     */
    auth?: {
        uid: string;
        token: firebase.auth.DecodedIdToken;
    };
    /**
     * An unverified token for a Firebase Instance ID.
     */
    instanceIdToken?: string;
    /**
     * The raw request handled by the callable.
     */
    rawRequest: Request;
}
```

As you can see, the `auth` property is marked as optional using a question mark.  This means that it could be undefined.  TypeScript is telling you that you need to check for that case before accessing it, in order to avoid bugs at runtime:

```
if (context.auth) {
    if (context.auth.token.moderator) {
        // ...
    }
}
```